# Is IPython 2.0 really ready?

Tags: pip, ipython, package, updates

According to `yolk`, IPython 2.0 is now available for installation

```
$ yolk -U
ipython 1.2.1 (2.0.0)
```

but there is [no announcement](http://ipython.org/news.html) of this on the IPython website, and the current stable version indicated there is 1.2.1.

Is IPython 2.0 stable and ready to install? Is this an April Fools?

Comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release was available before the [corresponding update to the notes](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/whatsnew/version2.0.html) on the website.